# Hide the Button when the Status Changed in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Implemented a Button, which calls for a function. That function actually sends a request to server to issue a credential. When user receives a Credential, Status of Credential is **Offered**, but when s/he clicks on This Button, it sends a request to server and the Status of Button change to **Received**.

I only wants to Show the Button when the Status of Button is **Offered**.

**CredentialPage.xml**

```
<Button x:Name="Button_Round"
WidthRequest="40"
HeightRequest="40"
CornerRadius="20"
BorderWidth="2"
TextColor="White"
BorderColor="Teal"
BackgroundColor="Teal"
Text="Accept Offer"
Command="{Binding ProcessOffer}" />
```

**CredentialViewModel.cs** => CreateRequestAsync() is the one, which sends request to server. When the request is sent successfully, I want to hide the button.

```
    public ICommand ProcessOffer => new Command(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            //await _poolConfigurator.ConfigurePoolsAsync();
            var agentContext = await _agentContextProvider.GetContextAsync();
            var credentialRecord = await _credentialService.GetAsync(agentContext, _credential.Id);
            var connectionId = credentialRecord.ConnectionId;
            var connectionRecord = await _connectionService.GetAsync(agentContext, connectionId);
            (var request, _) = await _credentialService.CreateRequestAsync(agentContext, _credential.Id);
            await _messageService.SendAsync(agentContext.Wallet, request, connectionRecord);
            await DialogService.AlertAsync("Request has been sent to the issuer.", "Success", "Ok");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await DialogService.AlertAsync("Pool is not correctly configured. Please add proper genesis file.\n("+e.Message+")","Pool Error","Ok");
        }
    });
```

If you could guide me, It will be very kind of you :)

Comment: Create a bool property that your button can observe to enable/disable, then set that bool property before/after your function call

Comment: can u please guide me with a little code, I don't know much about xamarin.

Comment: @MattGreen Hi, If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 3):

bind the `IsVisible` property to a VM property

```
<Button x:Name="Button_Round"  IsVisible="{Binding ButtonVisible}" ... />
```

then in your VM (your VM must implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
private bool _ButtonVisible = true;

public bool ButtonVisible
{
  get {
    return _ButtonVisible;
  }
  set {
     _ButtonVisible = value;
     PropertyChanged("ButtonVisible");
  }
 }
```

then whenever your receive the response from the server, you can set `ButtonVisible` to the appropriate value

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Change 'PropertyChanged' to 'IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged'"

Comment: are you using the Reactive framework?  If so, you should read their docs on using PropertyChanged